# magento: saving or viewing settings slow

Tags: magento

we have reviewed our magento performance. And it is OK, within limits now ;)

There are 2 exceptions

But! changing and editing settings (going to system, config) is just plain slow: viewing, and changing is almost impossible.

Also adding a product to the cart takes 10 secs.

Any advice on a special index I can set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add APC caching to the Magento backend
Sounds like mysql is struggling - try running mysqltuner.pl for some hints

Comment: Cant. No SSH. Thanks for the answer though, will ask provider. But what can we do to profile/debug cart performance, adding somethign to cart is ridiculous and takes 20 secs+ http://baleinen.com/baleinen-overhemd-plastic-strips.html

Answer (score 0):

Merci bien. We are looking into adding APC. Thx. Does it also speed up backend?

To update you on our issue. We installed Jirafe plugin. And what happened was is thta it couldnt connect and timed out only after 30 secs.

We filed a bug report with Jirafe for this. Dont think a live commercial site should give some logging and reporting framework more prio then actually doing sales.